# Android, missing symbol for Rust library being called from C++

Tags: android, c++, rust, cmake

I have a Rust library which I have compiled for Android as a static library (engine.a), this library contains some C-compatible (FFI) functions. [I've already figured out how to bind and call this library from Java](https://ospfranco.com/post/2023/08/11/react-native,-rust-step-by-step-integration-guide/). Now I want to call these functions from C++ (directly, no JNI).

After compiling this library, I've placed my generated files under `PROJECT_ROOT/android/jniLibs` which is the default location on which Android will automatically package them in the application:

```
android
  - jniLibs
    - arm64-v8a
       - engine.a
    - armeabi-v7a
       - engine.a
... // so on for the rest of supported archs
```

I've generated a header file (engine.h using `cbindgen`, all the functions are properly annotated with `no_mangle` and `extern "C"`) that containts the C compatible functions and placed it with my source C++ code. This is already working on iOS but on Android I'm facing an undefined symbol error.

Android Studio is happy, with the imported header and doesn't show me any errors in the editor:

```cpp
#include "engine.h"

...

int res = my_rust_fn();
```

On my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
        ${PACKAGE_NAME}
        SHARED
    ../cpp/bindings.cpp # contains my C++ that should call the functions in engine.h
    ../cpp/engine.h
    cpp-adapter.cpp
)

include_directories(
    ../cpp
)

set_target_properties(
  ${PACKAGE_NAME} PROPERTIES
  CXX_STANDARD 17
  CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
  POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
)

find_package(ReactAndroid REQUIRED CONFIG)
find_package(fbjni REQUIRED CONFIG)


target_link_libraries(
  ${PACKAGE_NAME}
  fbjni::fbjni
  ReactAndroid::jsi
  ReactAndroid::turbomodulejsijni
  ReactAndroid::react_nativemodule_core
  android
)
```

However, when the code is compiled I get an undefined symbol on `my_rust_fn` call:

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: my_rust_fn
>>> referenced by bindings.cpp:91
```

I also tried adding a find_package to the cmake lists with the name of the static library but to no success, it just throws an error:

```
find_package(engine REQUIRED CONFIG)

target_link_libraries(
$(PACKAGE_NAME)
engine
...
)
```

Any suggestion what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of your function in engine.h? Crucially, did you add `extern "C" `?

Comment: Yeah, the function is properly declared. Cannot show the code as it is proprietary and under NDA but I assure you the generated headers and functions are correct as I already got this working on iOS.

Comment: Which cmake target is supposed to contain your rust library? How do you link it to your shared library? Can you verify with `nm` that the symbol names for `my_rust_fn` match between the static library and bindings.o?

Comment: I think that is the part that I'm missing right? What I've posted is all that I have. I don't know how to tell CMake to go look for the symbol implementation in the corresponding `engine.a`

Comment: "I got it working in iOS" is not sufficient. Objective C does not do name mangling like C++ does. The `nm` test above should tell us if name mangling is being applied or not.

Comment: You can just add "engine.a" to `target_link_libraries`. Or make an IMPORTED target but it doesn't add much in this case.

Comment: I just added more details to my question. As I have multiple architectures don't know how to tell CMake to import the correct one?

Comment: I added `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/engine.a` and got a new error: ld: error: undefined symbol: deflate. However, this looks like a std error. Awesome! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Botje, he pointed me in the right direction. It is not enough to include the header file. The linker needs to know the location of the correct `.a` file to correctly link it at compile time.

I added the following to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(engine STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(engine PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/engine.a)

target_link_libraries(
  ${PACKAGE_NAME}
  engine
```

Tells the compiler to which architecture-specific version it needs to link against.